# Running Python files and seeing output

Tags: python, pandas, terminal

I started learning ML with Python and its libraries. I might have a bit stupid question but not sure how to proceed.

In this *main.py* file I want to import one file and see its tail.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', header = None)
df.tail()
```

When I compile it from Terminal, the data frame is not printed out on Terminal, i.e.

```
Lior ML Python $ python3 main.py
Lior ML Python $
```

Then I try running Python from the terminal and c/p these lines and then I can see my data frame is printed out.

```
Lior ML Python $ python3
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', header = None)
df.tail()

>>> df.tail()
       0    1    2    3               4
145  6.7  3.0  5.2  2.3  Iris-virginica
146  6.3  2.5  5.0  1.9  Iris-virginica
147  6.5  3.0  5.2  2.0  Iris-virginica
148  6.2  3.4  5.4  2.3  Iris-virginica
149  5.9  3.0  5.1  1.8  Iris-virginica
>>>
```

Why there is not output when compiling in Terminal, i.e. when I will have more complexed codes how can I compile their files and see the output without c/p them into terminal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print df.tail()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `print` it. If you execute `df.tail()` in your script without printing it, its return value gets lost (you don't assign it nor print it).

You should:

```
print df.tail()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same confusion as you when I first started learning Python. I started by using the command line to type instructions one-by-one. When you do that the results of each expression are printed.

However, when you put your commands into a script and run them you have to explicitly `print` every statement you wish to see.